# Spark add same row number based on value in cell

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have data as follows

```
//input data
df.show()
//+---+---+---+
//|  x|  y|  z|
//+---+---+---+
//|tes| 45| 34|
//|tes| 43| 67|
//|tes| 56| 43|
//|raj| 45| 43|
//|raj| 44| 67|
//+---+---+---+
```

I want this to be converted as with out changing the order of the given input.

```
//output data
    df.show()
    //+---+---+---+---+
    //|  x|  y|  z|  n|
    //+---+---+---+---+
    //|tes| 45| 34|  1|
    //|tes| 43| 67|  1|
    //|tes| 56| 43|  1|
    //|raj| 45| 43|  2|
    //|raj| 44| 67|  2|
    //+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: `I want this to be converted as with out changing the order of the given input.`, why so ? Spark does not really have order, you can still force it using `monotonically_increasing_id`, but it might cost you in performance.
Also, how is n incremented ? By new x ?

Comment: yes,if x value is same then the n value should be same. i the x value changes then n value should be incremented by 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea here is to find a way to add a new column with the information "is it a new x ?", and then to do a rolling sum to "add" these informations.

For this, we need a [`window`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/Window.html) function and the [`lag`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#lag-java.lang.String-int-java.lang.Object-) method.

```
// Some imports
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => F}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

// inputs
val df = Seq(("tes", 45, 34), ("tes", 43, 67), ("tes", 56, 43), ("raj", 45, 43), ("raj", 44, 67)).toDF("x", "y", "z")

// adding new information
val windowSpec = Window.orderBy(F.monotonically_increasing_id())


val dfWithNewNameInfo = df
  .withColumn("n", (F.lag($"x", 1).over(windowSpec) =!= $"x").cast("bigint"))
  .na.fill(1, Seq("n"))
dfWithNewNameInfo.show
/*
+---+---+---+---+
|  x|  y|  z|  n|
+---+---+---+---+
|tes| 45| 34|  1|
|tes| 43| 67|  0|
|tes| 56| 43|  0|
|raj| 45| 43|  1|
|raj| 44| 67|  0|
+---+---+---+---+


*/
// We can see the "1" in the last column indicates whenever this is a new x

// Adding these 1
val resultDf = dfWithNewNameInfo.withColumn("n", F.sum("n").over(windowSpec))
resultDf.show
/*
+---+---+---+---+
|  x|  y|  z|  n|
+---+---+---+---+
|tes| 45| 34|  1|
|tes| 43| 67|  1|
|tes| 56| 43|  1|
|raj| 45| 43|  2|
|raj| 44| 67|  2|
+---+---+---+---+
*/
```

This method gives the desired result for a small dataframe which can be fully loaded in memory.

---

Be aware the `windowSpec` order by the line, but this would fail for the following DataFrame:

```
//+---+---+---+
//|  x|  y|  z|
//+---+---+---+
//|tes| 45| 34|
//|tes| 43| 67|
//|raj| 45| 43|
//|raj| 44| 67|
//|tes| 56| 43|
//+---+---+---+
```

Giving the result:

```
//+---+---+---+---+
//|  x|  y|  z|  n|
//+---+---+---+---+
//|tes| 45| 34|  1|
//|tes| 43| 67|  1|
//|raj| 45| 43|  2|
//|raj| 44| 67|  2|
//|tes| 56| 43|  3|
//+---+---+---+---+
```

That is why I **strongly recommand** to order by `"x"` in the `windowSpec`.

Comment: NO i don't want change the order in case. This will not work.

Comment: @rakeeee have you tried the first part ? Given your inputs, this should work

Comment: The input is already ordered. SO i don't want change the order again. In you example the order is changed. I know `F.monotonically_increasing_id()` but without changing my input order.

Comment: @rakeeee I corrected the outputs, I made a wrong copy paste of my first try where I ordered by `x`, if you copy paste in a `spark-shell`, you will see this is working :)

Comment: what is `stringValueThatShouldNotBeInColx`, because i dynamic values in `col x`

Comment: @rakeeee I have updated the answer to avoid using hardcoded value as I have done, but filling the first row of `n` by 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this in Spark with Java,

```
df.withColumn("n", lag(col("x"), 1, "a").over(Window.orderBy(monotonicallyIncreasingId())).notEqual(col("x")).cast(DataTypes.LongType))
            .withColumn("n", sum("n").over(Window.orderBy(monotonicallyIncreasingId())));
```